# Text overflow ellipsis, in span between floated left span and a floated right span

Tags: overflow, css

I am having trouble ellipsis text (.title) found in between a span that is floated left and a span that is floated right. When overflow occurs .length is pushed down onto a new line. How can I fix this?

JS FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/VfHdS/6/

HTML:

```
<div class="song">
<span class="tracknumber">4</span>
<div class="title">This is the song tittle!!!!!!!!!!!</div>
<span class="length">4:31</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.song {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 2px 20px;
}
.tracknumber {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.title {
    color: #262626;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.length {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis;` works with block containers only. Read more at [W3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#text-overflow0)

Comment: Still no luck http://jsfiddle.net/VfHdS/6/.

Comment: @Sonu Joshi: An inline block is also a block container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sample html you provided I set up a fiddle. Setting the .title element to display block is what gets the ellipses to show up.

http://jsfiddle.net/f4uUJ/

I've also repositioned the track number and play time absolutely so the song title can be 100% width. You just need to add padding to the track to give the title some breathing room.

CSS

```
.song {
     font-size: 14px;
     padding: 2px 40px 2px 20px;
     position:relative;
}
.tracknumber {
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     top:2px;
}
.title {
     white-space: nowrap;
     width: 100%;
     display:block;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.length {
     position:absolute; 
     right:0;
     top:2px;
}
```